# `git submodule update --remote` vs `git pull --recurse-submodule` vs `git submodule foreach git pull origin main`

Tags: git, git-submodules

There are three commands that (as far as I know) can be used to update a git submodule to its latest version.

- `git submodule update --remote --recursive`
- `git pull --recurse-submodule`
- `git submodule foreach git pull origin main`

**What is the difference between the three commands?** There are already some questions on StackOverflow regarding this, but most of them explain this using concepts I do not understand (rebase and branch HEADs). I'm hoping someone can explain this to me in a simple way. I'm using submodules in my project to link it to other projects, and I would like to know what the difference between the three commands is. All three work for me locally, and I would like to know which one is the most appropriate one for me to use.

**I would also like to know what the two options on these commands do.** `--recurse-submodule` is quite self-evident. `git pull` would only pull the main repo otherwise. But what does the `--remote` option on `git submodule update` do? What about the `--recursive` option? I'm assuming the `--recursive` option is to target submodules inside submodules, but I'm not able to figure out what `--remote` does.

I realize that `git submodule update` will initially clone the repos mentioned in `.gitmodules`, but I'm asking about what happens when a version of the repo already exists. Does it update that version to the latest commit or not?

**What happens when I run this in a CI/CD tool like GitHub Actions?** Only the `.gitmodules` file will be present, so will `git submodule update` update that to the latest commits or will it just clone the submodule repos, which is kind of pointless since the "local" cache will be cleared once the workflow finishes running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `git submodule update --remote --recursive`

This command updates all submodules (and their submodules because of `--recursive`) to use the latest commit on the default branch of their repository (e.g. `main`, `master`). You can change the branch per submodule in `.gitmodules`. To quote the official documentation:

> You can, however, set this to something different if you want. For
> example, if you want to have the DbConnector submodule track that
> repository’s “stable” branch, you can set it in either your
> .gitmodules file (so everyone else also tracks it), or just in your
> local .git/config file. Let’s set it in the .gitmodules file:
>
> `$ git config -f .gitmodules submodule.DbConnector.branch stable`

If `--remote` wasn't used, it'd go for specific commits already recorded for each submodule by the main repository.

### `git pull --recurse-submodule`

This works similarly to `git submodule update --recursive`, except it of course also pulls changes for the main repository.

### `git submodule foreach git pull origin main`

This one updates each submodule (but not their submodules) to use latest commit on the `main` branch. It's not really safe to use as different submodules could use different branch names, e.g. `master`. I wouldn't recommend ever using it over `git submodule update --remote`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Late answer, but perfect 

Comment: @Destroy666 can you elaborate on "it'd go for specific commits already recorded for each submodule by the main repository"? im having a hard time grasping the use of `--remote`

Comment: @gosuto sure, but what kind of elaboration do you need? What would be your question(s)?